# jQuery - add html based on class name

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a way to add some html based on a certain class name and inject it into a specific place. The code belows shows what i am trying to do, but this is obvioulsy hard coded, i want to do it dynamically using jQuery.

```
<ul class="status clrfix">
<li class="green"><a href="">Completed</a><span class="arrow"></span></li>
<li class="green"><a href="">Completed</a><span class="arrow"></span></li>
<li class="blue"><a href="">In Progress</a><span class="current-stage"><img src="images/current-stage.png" /></span><span class="arrow"></span></li>
<li>Not Started <span class="arrow"></span></li>
<li class="last">Not Started <span class="arrow"></span></li>
```

So, essentially what i want to do is; if the class="blue" then add this inside the li:

```
<span class="current-stage"><img src="images/current-stage.png" /></span>
```

This is what i attempted, but it's not working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

if($('ul.status li').hasClass('.blue')){
    $("span.current-stage").empty().html('<img src="../images/current-stage.png" />');
}
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your if statement to the following:

```
if($('ul.status li').hasClass('blue')){
```

The [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method accepts a class name as a parameter, not a selector. So you can leave out the `.` on the front of the class.

Also, if you wish to add HTML to without removing what is already there, use the [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function.

```
$("span.current-stage").append('<span class="current-stage"><img src="../images/current-stage.png" /></span>');
```

Comment: Wow! that was fast and it is injecting the image fine. Howver, what i would really like to do is inject not only the image, but the span also, something like this:

Comment: if($('ul.status li').hasClass('blue')){
    $().empty().html('<span class="current-stage"><img src="images/current-stage.png" /></span>');
 }

Comment: No worries, I've updated the answer to show you how to "add". Using the `html()` function will basically replace what's already there and clear your `In Progress` text. So I'd suggest using `append()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
$('ul.status li.blue span.current-stage').empty().html('<img src="../images/current-stage.png" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try
        $("span.current-stage").html('');
or you can also use .append method .

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can use only CSS for the same result :

```
ul.status li.blue span.current-stage {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.status li span.current-stage {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: So how would i show it and inject my image? That will just not display anything.

Comment: With this solution, you don't need jQuery code. The CSS automatically hides the span.current-stage when the li doesn't have the blue class.